# C# XAML InputScope="Number" present unneeded special characters

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, inputscope

I am trying to present only a numeric keyboard. I keep getting the special character region of characters on the left while I would just like to have the num pad region on the right.

(See Image Below)

[image]

XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name ="EmployeeId" InputScope="Number" />
```

C#:

```
var inputScope = new InputScope ();
var inputScopeName = new InputScopeName();
inputScopeName.NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.Number;
inputScope.Names.Add(inputScopeName);
EmployeeId.InputScope = inputScope;
```

I have read:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.inputscopenamevalue.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn792128
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh393998(v=vs.105).aspx

I have also searched stackoverflow posts.

Does anyone know how to get my Window RT application to show only the numeric pad. Is what is presented below expected when InputScope is Number, TelephoneNumber or NumberFullWidth?

Thank you.
Dan

**[Edit Below (possible solution)]**

I decided to create a new application and try...

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column ="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"   Width ="300">
        <TextBox Header ="Telephone Number" InputScope="TelephoneNumber"/>
        <TextBox Header ="Pin" InputScope="NumberFullWidth"/>
        <TextBox Header ="Numeric Password" InputScope="Number"/>
        <TextBox Header ="Web site" InputScope="Url"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

In a Windows Store Application, you get the behavior the picture above. In a Window Phone application you get the results I just the number pad. Bah... It was really simple to recreate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only numbers to be displayed you can use this piece of code

```
 InputScope="TelephoneNumber"
```

--please mark the answer if found satisfactory as others with the same problem might find the answer easily.

Comment: this is not the solution. My question actually states that I have tried your suggestion. Apparently there is not a number pad ONLY for Windows RT. Yes, using the window's phone framework, your suggestion would work. But, for Window's RT framework, you get the image posted above. Since my client only wanted a number pad, I just recreated it with buttons.